# quartz schdeuler for multiple projects in jboss 5

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I have deployed two projects (p1 & p2) in JBoss 5. Both projects are configured with different quartz schedulers. But when I schedule the job for p1 it is accessing the p2 database and inserting a row in QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS table. When I schedule the job for p2 then its working fine.

Help me to resolve the issue.

my quartz-service.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
<mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService"
name="user:service=QuartzService,name=p1">
<depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MsSqlDSp1</depends>
<attribute name="Properties">
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.
#
# org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class = 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
#org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true 
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 100000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
#org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
#org.quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore
#org.quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.updateLockRowSQL = UPDATE {0}LOCKS SET LOCK_NAME = LOCK_NAME WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QUARTZ
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = QUARTZ_NO_TX
#org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = dbo.QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ.jndiURL = java:MsSqlDSp1
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.jndiURL = java:MsSqlDSp1
</attribute>
</mbean>
<mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService"
name="user:service=QuartzService,name=QuartzServicep2">
<depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MsSqlDSp2</depends> 
<attribute name="Properties">
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.
#
# org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class = 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QUARTZ
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = QUARTZ_NO_TX
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ.jndiURL = java:/MsSqlDSp2
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.jndiURL = java:/MsSqlDSp2
</attribute>
</mbean>
</server>
```

jms-ds.xml

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService" name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=p1BatchQ" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
<depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends> 
<depends>jboss.messaging:service=pf</depends> 
<attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">1</attribute>
</mbean> 
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService" name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=p2BatchQ" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
<depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends> 
<depends>jboss.messaging:service=pf</depends> 
<attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">1</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Comment: Try with different `org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName` for each configuration.